# My Sepia filter is not working as expected, although in certain cases it does work

Tags: c, rgb, cs50

For my online CS50 course I have to convert an image to Sepia.

I have built this function that should take each pixel and sets the RGB value to Sepia.
The program loads an image via the command prompt and converts its to Sepia.
The programs loads the picture fine, and it also creates a new picture.
Only problem is it is not Sepia. Online I can check my program, here it sometimes calculates the new pixel correct but other times it is wrong. I cannot see any connections on why it works only with some pixels. Probably has to do with the values of the pixel, but I cannot see the input. The formula for sepia was given by Harvard CS50.

Here is a link to the results: https://submit.cs50.io/check50/66b21d4d9453a5e671bb0862bb016a420a73893b

Here is the code that should change the image to Sepia.

```
// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //Calculates the sepia value of image[i][j].rgbtRed
           int red = round((image[i][j].rgbtRed *.393)+(image[i][j].rgbtGreen *.769)+(image[i][j].rgbtBlue *.189));
            //the value can be max 255, if it is higher it should be capped at 255
            if (red > 255)
           {
                red = 255;
           }

            //Calculates the sepia value of image[i][j].rgbtGreen
           int green = round((image[i][j].rgbtRed *.349)+(image[i][j].rgbtGreen *.686)+(image[i][j].rgbtBlue *.168));
           if (green > 255)
           {
                green = 255;
           }

            //Calculates the sepia value of image[i][j].rgbtblue
           int blue = round((image[i][j].rgbtRed *.272)+(image[i][j].rgbtGreen *.534)+(image[i][j].rgbtBlue *.131));
           if (blue > 255)
           {
                blue = 255;
           }


           //sets the image[i][j] values to the Sepia equavalent
           image[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
           image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
           image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
        }

    return;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Online I can check ..." What is the result? In which cases does the program fail? How? Is it off-by-one or completely off? Can you provide the link to the detailled results?

Comment: I have added the link, sorry forgotten to include it.

Comment: Your 'return' statement is in the wrong place. It's inside the outermost loop. It needs to be one scope out.

Comment: Stepping through your code in a debugger should tell you that you return from that function after the first row. Reason is misplaced `return` as mentioned by pmacfarlane. You should get used to run you rcode in a debugger. In case of such test-sites that may include that you need to write test code that provides the data from the failed test case to your function

Comment: @pmacfarlane
I'm even wondering why there is a 'return' in the first place: it's a void method afterall

Comment: Makes so much sense, yes I see it now! thanks!! The Code works! I'll also watch some more tutorials on the debugger to better understand it.